# Cipher suites vulnerable to logjam

Tags: diffie-hellman

The following is a list of ciphers, how to know which ciphers are vulnerable to LogJam attack?

Client shared list of ciphers:

1. TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
2. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
3. TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
4. TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
5. TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
6. TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
7. TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
8. TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
9. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
10. TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
11. TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
12. TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
13. TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
14. TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
15. TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
16. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
17. TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
18. TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
19. TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
20. TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
21. TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV

Server chosen cipher: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Comment: [Look under "What you should do"](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89689/what-is-logjam-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Don't use `_DSS_` (it's not supported these days anyway), don't use `_RC4_` (it's broken and deprecated), don't use `_ECDH_` (nobody supports it anyway, but still, ECDHE is what you want). You've not listed AEAD (AES-GCM) cipher suites, these are the only ones that are considered secure. Add them. Reorder the list to be: ECDHE+ECDSA+AESGCM, ECDHE+aRSA+AESGCM, DHE+aRSA+AESGCM, ECDHE+ECDSA+AES, ECDHE+aRSA+AES, DHE+aRSA+AES, RSA+AES, RSA+3DES. The first three are secure, the next 3 at least provide PFS, the last 2 are for compatibility. DHE is really secure only if you use at least 2048 bit DHE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, DH export cipher is vulnerable to logjam attack, but the list its being hard to find which are all DH export cipher

Answer (score 6):

Any with `_DHE_` in them. Those are the ones that use Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman, `_ECDHE_` is safe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,What i understood is anything starting with _DHE is vulnerable to logjam attack.  ECDHE is safe, is that right?

Comment: Yes. There is no known similar exploit for the Elliptic curve version of Diffie–Hellman (ECDH).

Comment: For more info see my answers to these questions: [Securing Chrome against Logjam on Windows](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90046/securing-chrome-against-logjam-on-windows/90061) and [How to Check if a server is not vulnerable to logjam?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/how-to-check-if-a-server-is-not-vulnerable-to-logjam/89775)